# How to properly integrate google chart with php

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I have  **3 columns(tea,milk,pepsi)** in a table with their respective values being inserted

When I integrate it with Google charts, things seems to partly works fine.

My **main issue** is how to make the column name **tea,milk,pepsi** appears at the bottom for their respective columns at the horizontal axis,

**Here is the code**

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(column_chart);

function column_chart() {
    var res = $.ajax({
    url: 'chart.php',
    dataType:"json",
    async: false,
    success: function(res)
    {
      var options = {'title':'Foods Items', 'width':800, 'height':400,
      series: {
                0: { color: 'purple' },
                1: { color: 'navy' },
              
              }
    };    
    
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(res);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_data'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    
    }
    }).responseText;
 }
        
    <?php
    
    include('db.php');
    
    $data[] = array('Foods Items', 'Tea','Milk', 'Pepsi');   
   
    $res = $db->prepare('SELECT 
    tea AS value_tea,
    milk AS value_milk,
    pepsi AS value_pepsi FROM foods');
    $res->execute(array());

    while($row = $res->fetch()) {   
      $tea = $row['value_tea'];
      $milk = $row['value_milk'];
      $pepsi = $row['value_pepsi'];
      $fd= 'Provisions';
      $data[] = array($fd,(int)$tea,(int)$milk,(int)$pepsi);
    }
      
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Here is the screenshot showing where I want to add the table column name **tea,milk and pepsi** as indicated by **arrow.**

Any solution or alternative will be appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently, your data is structured as follows...

```
[
  ['Foods Items', 'Tea', 'Milk', 'Pepsi'],
  ['Provisions', 35, 66, 48]
]
```

to get the desired chart, re-structure your data as follows...

```
[
  ['Foods Items', 'Provisions']
  ['Tea', 35]
  ['Milk', 66]
  ['Pepsi', 48]
]
```

this will create a label under each bar.
however, this also puts all the food items into one series.
so you will probably want to add a style column, in order to give each bar a different color...

```
[
  ['Foods Items', 'Provisions', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}]
  ['Tea', 35, 'purple']
  ['Milk', 66, 'navy']
  ['Pepsi', 48, 'gold']
]
```